# airflow tasks are runnning only once when externally triggered and not as specified in time interval mentioned in default arguements

Tags: loops, task, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have specified the time interval of 5 minutes(using cron expression */5 * * * *) and this is expected to run the task after every five minutes. But this is not happening. Instead, the task is running only when I trigger the dag manually.

This is my code:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 07, 8),
    'email': ['shubhamkalyankari01@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 3,
    'schedule_interval': '*/5 * * * *',
        'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
}
```

Comment: Any error in webserver or scheduler logs?

Comment: Have you checked that ```scheduler``` is running?

Comment: i have run the scheduler using command- airflow scheduler, still the problem persists.

Comment: and also there is no error  while running scheduler and webserver.

Comment: OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'airflow'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)     ----this is the error showing while i start airflow scheduler.